# How do i pass an action between controllers parent and child Ember?

Tags: ember.js

So i want to be able to press a button on the parent which passes an action to the child controller which would toggle a value ?

Is this possible? I have only read about passing actions to components not between controllers ?

Answer (score 6):

Have property say `isOpen` and `toggleIsOpen` in parent controller. In child controller you can inject parent controller and use `isOpen` property and use `send('toggleIsOpen')` to call parent controller method.

[Twiddle Link](https://ember-twiddle.com/81c391f442e2c7750f201afa9a9c85aa?openFiles=router.js%2C&route=%2Fchild) which demonstrate

controllers/parent.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isOpen:true,
  actions:{
    toggleIsOpen(){
      console.log('toggleIsOpen in parent');
      this.toggleProperty('isOpen');
    }
  }
});
```

controllers/parent/child.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  parent: Ember.inject.controller('parent'), 
  actions:{
    toggleIsOpen(){      
      this.get('parent').send('toggleIsOpen');      
    }
  }
});
```

templates/parent/child.hbs

```
child {{parent.isOpen}} 
<button {{action 'toggleIsOpen' }}> Toggle </button>
{{outlet}}
```